# JQuery Datatables Width

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using JQuery Datatables in my Laravel project. I have an problem on column width. My second column have to much text. And thats the reason my table is turning mobile version.

```
            $('#example').DataTable({
                responsive: true,
                autoWidth: false,
                language: {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.24/i18n/Turkish.json"
                },
                order: [
                    [7, "desc"],
                ],
                columnDefs: [{
                        targets: [0],
                        width: "25%"
                    },
                    {
                        targets: [1],
                        width: "5px"
                    },
                    {
                        targets: [2],
                        width: "10%"
                    },
                    {
                        targets: [3],
                        width: "10%"
                    },
                    {
                        targets: [4],
                        width: "20%"
                    },
                    {
                        targets: [5],
                        width: "10%"
                    },
                    {
                        orderable: false,
                        targets: [6],
                        width: "15%"
                    },
                    {
                        targets: [7],
                        width: "5%"
                    },
                ],
```

This is my code's width area. How can I fix this problem? I try:

- responsive: true
- autoWidth: false
- word-wrap: break-word
  However there are not work.